# How to listen to custom element events in Vue?

Tags: vuejs3, custom-element, material-components-web

I'm using custom elements (specifically [Material Web Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/tree/mwc/packages/drawer)) but I can't figure out how to listen to events from custom elements using the usual `v-on` syntax.

The following doesn't work:

```html
<mwc-drawer ref='drawer' v-on='{"MDCDrawer:opened": opened}'>
```

Where as this does:

```js
onMounted(() => {
    drawer.value.addEventListener('MDCDrawer:opened', () => {
        console.log('opened')
    })
})
```

Does Vue only listen to native events rather than custom ones when it thinks it is a native element (but actually a custom element)?

Comment: Have you seen (and read) the Vue documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events

Comment: Yes, I don't believe this specific use case is described in the docs. There's docs on creating custom elements but not much on using them within a vue app.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### explain

only when we emit the custom event, we can listen on use.
in mwc-drawer.vue we should emit the MDCDrawer:opened event.
and then we can use v-on={"MDCDrawer:opened": fn} or @MDCDrawer:opened="fn" listen

[**official site**](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments)

### demo

- mwc-drawer.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'

const emit = defineEmits(['MDCDrawer:opened'])

function open() {
  // only when we emit the custom event, we can listen on use
  emit('MDCDrawer:opened', { text: 'Hello!!' })
}
</script>
```

- home.vue

```html
<template>
  <mwc-drawer ref='drawer' v-on='{"MDCDrawer:opened": opened}' />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
function opened(params) {
  console.log(params) // { text: 'Hello!!' }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, if that's the case then Vue can't listen to custom element events and I'll file an issue to request support.